# Como barrar a inscrição de um usuário já inscrito

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que gerencia **Cursos** em asp.net MVC, ainda sou iniciante, e estou tentando fazer o seguinte: O Aluno tem uma tela onde lista todos os cursos para ele escolher e fazer sua inscrição em algum desses cursos. **Esta parte eu já fiz**, porem, preciso fazer o seguinte controle, onde, caso esse aluno **se inscreva em um curso**, por exemplo, sistemas de informação, **ele não poderá se inscrever nesse mesmo** curso porque ele já está inscrito, o sistema **deve barrar e não deixar ele fazer duas inscrições no mesmo curso.**

**Minha Action Inscrição**

```
    // GET
    public ActionResult Inscricao()
    {
        //Aqui eu pego o Aluno logado
        Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        if (aluno == null)
            return View("MeusCursos");

        //Aqui ficaria a parte onde verifica se o aluno já está inscrito em algum curso

        return View(db.Cursos.ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Inscricao(int inscricaoId)
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            //Aqui eu pego o Aluno logado
            Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            if (aluno == null)
                return View("MeusCursos");

            //Aqui ficaria a parte onde verifica se o aluno já está inscrito em algum curso

            var curso = db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == inscricaoId);
            if (curso == null)
                return View("MeusCursos");

            var alunoCurso = new AlunoCurso
            {
                Aluno = aluno,
                Curso = curso
            };

            db.AlunoCursos.Add(alunoCurso);
            db.SaveChanges();

            curso.Qtd_Vagas--;
            db.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            scope.Complete();
        }

        return View(db.Cursos.ToList());
    }
```

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda nesse caso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo, na verdade. Falta apenas a verificação de `AlunoCurso`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Inscricao(int inscricaoId)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        //Aqui eu pego o Aluno logado
        Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (aluno == null)
            return View("MeusCursos");

        // Aqui ficaria a parte onde verifica se o aluno já está inscrito em algum curso.
        // Repare que, no seu código antigo, você apenas verifica se o curso
        // existe, e não se o aluno está inscrito nele.
        // Em todo caso, mantive o código antigo porque continua sendo importante 
        // verificar se o curso existe, para evitar usos indevidos do sistema.

        var curso = db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == inscricaoId);
        if (curso == null)
            return View("MeusCursos");

        // Aqui eu faço a verificação de fato se o aluno está inscrito no
        // curso ou não.
        var alunoCurso = db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Curso.Id == inscricaoId && ac.Aluno.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (alunoCurso != null)
            return View("MeusCursos");            

        alunoCurso = new AlunoCurso
        {
            Aluno = aluno,
            Curso = curso
        };

        db.AlunoCursos.Add(alunoCurso);
        db.SaveChanges();

        curso.Qtd_Vagas--;
        db.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        scope.Complete();
    }

    return View(db.Cursos.ToList());
}
```

Repare que simplifiquei `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` para `User.Identity.Name`. São equivalentes.

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui @Cigano, mas ainda conseguir me inscrever em um curso em que já estava inscrito.

Comment: Funcionou @Cigano, eu tinha esquecido do if. Como eu faço pra exibir uma mensagem para o Aluno que ele já está inscrito?

Comment: @Novato Você pode usar `ModelState.AddModelError("", "Aluno já está inscrito no curso.");`. A mensagem irá aparecer onde estiver marcado com `@Html.ValidationSummary()`.